# Can I make website for a mosque?

Tags: masjid

**As-Salam-o-Alaikum To All**,

I want to make a website for my area's masjid(mosque) as a kind gift to home of Allah, but I am not sure whether this is allowed within Islam?

If the idea is permissible in general, what kinds of contents are allowed on the website?

Allah Hafiz to All.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be allowed?

Comment: Thanks @Daniel to revamped my question, now its too appropriate to understand.

Comment: The web in general is a tool, which can be use for good and bad.  Just like a pen is a tool which can be used for good and bad.  i've never heard anyone ask if it's ok to write a leaflet for a musjid, so why would it not be ok to write a website for musjid?  As long as it's doesn't break islamic rules, there is no problem isha'allah.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allah encourages you to [spend](http://quran.com/2/254) in his cause. This can be your money or energy. If He has given you a particular skill, then what's better way of thanking him other than giving it [back](http://quran.com/2/245) to Him.

So please do make this website and May Allah accept it from you, as He will not waste a deed as small as a grain.

Comment: nice answer, developing website for a masjid won't be a donation to it